# Animation disappears when attempting to center text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using particles.js to set a full screen particle effect, I specified I wanted this animation full-screen by using `height: 100vh;` this has worked perfectly and has fulfilled what I wanted to achieve. I then tried to add text on top of my particle animation and then proceed to vertically center it using `line-height: 100vh;`. Although when doing this my animation stops and turns to a pure grey background and my text is centered? I want my animation to continue running with the text on top of it (being centered), I am unsure what to do to stop my text messing my animation. I have included a video below of what is happening.

[Video (Streamable)](https://streamable.com/fxvtq)

**HTML**

```
<div id="particles-js">
  <div id="main-text">Center Me</div>
</div>

<!--Scripts-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.js"></script>
<script>
particlesJS.load('particles-js' , 'particles.json', function(){console.log('particles.json loaded...')})
</script>
<!--End Of Scripts-->
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#particles-js{
  background:#4a4a4a; 
  height: 100vh;
}

#main-text{
    text-align: center;
    /* line-height: 100vh; */
}
```

Comment: Given the fact you want to overlay text, try adding this to your I'd #main-text{position: absolute}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to change the way you're centering the text to this :

```
#main-text{
    /*text-align: center;*/
    /* line-height: 100vh; */
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I believe this is because the line-height is covering the entire viewport, even if the font is still small ( I can't say for sure this is the case, it's just an assumption )